# Python code navigation in PyCharm vs VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, pylance, code-navigation

I use VSCode with Python and Pylance extensions. Basic navigation works fine, however when code involves references from function parameters code navigation doesn't work.

For example following scenario works in PyCharm but doesn't work in VSCode. In the code below when I Ctrl+click *parent_b_func1* on `ins_B.parent_b_func1(A())` it is able to locate the function definition. However when I do Ctrl+click *parent_a_func1* on `param_a.parent_a_func1()` it cannot locate the definition.

```python
class ParentA(object):
    def parent_a_func1(self):
        print("Hi!")


class A(ParentA):
    def a_func1(self):
        pass


class ParentB(object):
    def parent_b_func1(self, param_a):
        param_a.parent_a_func1()
        pass


class B(ParentB):
    def b_func1(self, ):        
        pass


ins_B = B()

ins_B.parent_b_func1(A())
```

- VSCode version 1.83.1
- Python extension version v2023.18.0
- Pylance extension version v2023.10.50

Comment: You need to type hint `param_a` to `A` like `param_a: A`.

Comment: if you hover over `param_a` it tells you the type is `Any`

Comment: If you find the solution, please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)